# query of complex document like a matrix in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Some document has the following schema. The structure of documents resembles a Matrix. Each element of the matrix is the key-value pair `{k:1, v:".."}`. Some elements in the row may be absent.

```
{
  doc: {
    matrix: [
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}],
     [{k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:".."}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:3; v:".."}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}],
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:".."}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:7; v:".."}]
    ]
  }
}
```

In the document above the first row of the matrix has all 7 elements. The second row has only 3 elements. and so on.

Is there any simple way to get rows contain the element with the key=3 and value="foo"?

The output should be:

```
{
  doc: {
    matrix: [
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}]
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mongoose, but in mongodb shell it is possible to achieve following output, using [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/):

```
> db.collectionName.aggregate({$unwind: "$doc.matrix"}, {$match: {"doc.matrix": {k: 3, v: 'foo'}}}, {$group: {_id: "$_id", "matrix": {$push: "$doc.matrix"}}})["result"]

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("545237a78916011a82e4a33e"),
  matrix: [
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}]
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}],
     [{k:1; v:".."}, {k:2; v:".."}, {k:3; v:"foo"}, {k:4; v:".."}, {k:5; v:".."}, {k:6; v:".."}, {k:7; v:".."}]
    ]
}
```

Note, that output structure is a little bit different, i.e there is no `'doc'` field. But if you can deal with it, the response is correct.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this without aggregation? I would like to have the most effective solution. If there is no another effective solution I will think about how to change the document structure.

Comment: @Roman another way, that comes to my mind, is to process the mongo output in the ODM (mongoose). I.e. first you get only those documents, that have at least one matrix row with needed values (`db.collectionName.find({'doc.matrix': {'k': 3, 'v': 'foo'}}`, better check this query, i'm not sure in it) and then drop those matrix rows, that are not match needed values.